# Farm configuration wizard not making "State Service"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, configuration-wizard

I am trying to run Farm Configuration wizard for the first time and using it I am just installing "State Service".

When I click "Next" then after a long time (probably 10 minutes) it says "Request timed out"

I checked logs and found the following error:

> Application error when access /_admin/adminconfigservicesresults.aspx,
>   Error=Request timed out
>
> System.Web.HttpException: Request timed out
>
> Getting Error Message for Exception System.Web.HttpException
>   (0x80004005): Request timed out

I have a 3 server farm, 1 APP and 2 WFE and I have stopped Web Application service on APP. I thought may be this is the cause of this error so I started the service on APP but I am getting same error. I have tried iisreset and computer restart many times.

I am logged in as local admin which installed SharePoint and is also part of Farm Admin group.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out SharePoint Timer Service was not running due to log on failure. I entered passport again and restarted service and now I hope everything is fine.